# Android picker widget for arbitrary strings

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm looking to make a basic picker in Android that looks like the built-in date and time pickers but uses a custom array of strings instead of dates and times:

[image]

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

This is probably one of the most basic questions and I see lots of custom pickers and wheels floating around, but I would particularly want this to have the same look and feel as the built-in pickers. What is the best way to do this?

Edit: so I'm using `TimePicker` widget to display a time selector, but what can I use to select from a list of arbitrary strings instead?

Comment: create a custom dialog and populate ui elements accordingly

Comment: well, that's kind of what i'm missing, which UI elements should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The look and feel comes from [android.widget.NumberPicker](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java)

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: It's actually even simpler than that, apparently just using `String[] values = .....; picker.setDisplayedValues(values);` will do the trick, where `picker` is a `NumberPicker`.